# Can the std::vector range constructor invoke explicit conversions?

Tags: c++, c++17

Is the following program well-formed?

```
#include <vector>
struct A {
    explicit A(int) {}
};
int main() {
    std::vector<int> vi = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector<A> va(vi.begin(), vi.end());
}
```

According to C++17 [sequence.reqmts], the requirement for

```
X u(i, j);
```

where `X` is a sequence container, is:

> `T` shall be `EmplaceConstructible` into `X` from `*i`.

However, in the preceding paragraph it is stated that:

> `i` and `j` denote iterators satisfying input iterator requirements and refer to elements implicitly convertible to `value_type`,

Thus it seems to me that both requirements would need to be met: the value type of the range must be implicitly convertible to the value type of the container, *and* `EmplaceConstructible` must be satisfied (which means the allocator must be able to perform the required initialization). Since `int` is not implicitly convertible to `A`, this program should be ill-formed.

However, surprisingly, [it seems to compile under GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c9dd43b0c8aee12).

Comment: (For the record, it's not only gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/ULeRDw)

Comment: In this case no implicit conversion is required, as the explicit constructor already fits the type. I think the description is confusing, but explicit construction is always better then implicit conversion before construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only a requirement for sequence containers to support the construction from iterators that satisfy the criteria of implicit convertibility.

This does not by itself disallow sequence containers to from supporting that construction from iterators that don't satisfy that criteria as far as I can tell<sup>1</sup>. There is explicit rule about that:

> If the constructor ... is called with a type InputIterator that does not *qualify as an input iterator*, then the constructor shall not participate in overload resolution.

It is unclear what "qualify as an input iterator" means exactly in the context. Is it informal way to express Cpp17InputIterator, or does it attempt to refer to requirements of i and j? I don't know. Whether it is allowed or not, standard doesn't have a strict requirement for detecting it:

> [container.requirements.general]
>
> The behavior of certain container member functions and deduction guides depends on whether types qualify as input iterators or allocators.
> The extent to which an implementation determines that a type cannot be an input iterator is unspecified, except that as a minimum integral types shall not qualify as input iterators. ...

With the interpretation that any Cpp17InputIterator "qualifies as an input iterator", the example program would not be required to be ill-formed. But it is not guaranteed to be well-formed either.

<sup>1</sup>In such case, it might be considered a quality of implementation issue to warn when relying on it. On the other hand, this limitation to implicit conversions may be considered a [defect](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3297).

---

P.S. This compiles without warnings in Clang (with libc++) and Msvc as well.

P.P.S. This wording seems to have been added in C++11 (which is natural, as then were explicit constructors also introduced).

Comment: Really depends on what [_"does not qualify as an input iterator"_](http://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts#13.1) means. Unlike [above](http://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts#3), it does not actually say `Cpp17InputIterator`, so it's not clear to me whether _"and refer to elements implicitly convertible to `value_type`"_ is included in "input iterator". If it is, then the constructor should not participate in overload resolution and the program should be ill-formed.

Comment: So, every standard library class is allowed to have extra constructors without issuing a diagnostic when those extra constructors are used? That intuitively seems wrong to me...

Comment: @Brian I'm not sure if its "extra constructors", but maybe more "specific implementations of constructors that allow for more room". Checking every input might have significant performance impact, so I don't know if that would be the way to go...

Comment: @Brian It would certainly be a bad idea even if not explicitly disallowed. In this case we are only considering whether a required constructor is allowed to support types of iterators that it is not required to support. In this case there is explicit "shall not participate" requirement as pointed out by Max, which would certainly disallow this. But it is indeed unclear what "qualify as an input iterator" means exactly in the context. Is it informal way to express `Cpp17InputIterator`, or does it attempt to refer to requirements of `i` and `j`? I don't know.

Comment: 1) [In C++ we set the standard low.](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general#17.sentence-2). 2) Constructors are [non-virtual member functions](http://eel.is/c++draft/member.functions#2). 3) See [LWG 3297](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3297); however I'm not particularly convinced that we should remove the implicit conversion requirement.